# Django vs. Model View Controller

Tags: django, model-view-controller, frameworks

Can somebody explain me where the diferences are between Django and the Model View Controller pattern?

Functionally, what can we expect from those differences — i.e. what works differently comparing Django to, for example, Ruby on Rails?

Comment: When you say “the” Model View Controller, do you mean the general pattern, or a specific implementation (like Ruby on Rails)?

Comment: This question doesn't qualify as 'not constructive' & has a straight forward answer without "debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". Why close it then?

Comment: not constructive? SO super mods strike again.

Comment: As of today, almost 24,000 people found this question constructive.  Including myself.

Comment: As of 2017, this question is still constructive

Comment: 2018 and still here...

Comment: 2052, still constructive

Comment: Yea, back from future into 2019 and still makes a lot of sense. Can a mod please open this (and may be make it protected, if at all required)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

According to the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com), Django follows the MVC pattern closely enough to be called an MVC framework.

Django has been referred to as an MTV framework because the controller is handled by the framework itself and most of the excitement happens in models, templates and views.

You can read more about MTV / MVC here:

[The MTV (or MVC) Development Pattern](http://djangobook.com/model-view-controller-design-pattern/)

> If you’re familiar with other MVC
> Web-development frameworks, such as
> Ruby on Rails, you may consider Django
> views to be the *controllers* and
> Django templates to be the *views*.
>
> This is an unfortunate confusion
> brought about by differing
> interpretations of MVC.
>
> In Django’s interpretation of MVC, the *view*
> describes the data that gets presented
> to the user; it’s not necessarily just
> how the data looks, but which data is
> presented.
>
> In contrast, Ruby on Rails
> and similar frameworks suggest that
> the controller’s job includes deciding
> which data gets presented to the user,
> whereas the view is strictly how the
> data looks, not which data is
> presented.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Coming from Rails to Django, this answers one of the things I found most frustrating: why does django put the controller code in a file called views.py!?

Comment: @dgmdan It's just a default convention, you can choose the name you like. But I agree, it seems weird :)

Comment: I would rather leave views.py as a view layer and create a set of controller classes into a controller package to avoid Django's confusion.

Comment: @dgmda: Becuase the concept of a "controller" is a misnomer in webapps. MVC is an event driven framework that doesn't fit only HTTP's stateless REQUEST/RESPONSE model. It shouldn't be called MVC in the first place. Almost all webapps are not MVC, but uses a model and a function or class usually called a View. The View in turn can delegate the HTML rendering to a Template, but doesn't need to. So there isn't a controller, actually.

Comment: I back Lennart Regebro's concept that a stateless model like HTTP shouldn't have a controller and an MVC model for webapps just brings about major confusion

Comment: Can this be considered as the reverse MVC pattern?

Comment: As others have commented, Django's alternate terminology is quite confusing when you start using it. Thanks for clarifying. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 26):

The Django FAQ itself is a decent place to start:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

> In our interpretation of MVC, the “view” describes the data that gets presented to the user. It’s not necessarily how the data looks, but which data is presented. The view describes which data you see, not how you see it. It’s a subtle distinction.
>
> ...
>
> Furthermore, it’s sensible to separate content from presentation – which is where templates come in. In Django, a “view” describes which data is presented, but a view normally delegates to a template, which describes how the data is presented.
>
> Where does the “controller” fit in, then? In Django’s case, it’s probably the framework itself: the machinery that sends a request to the appropriate view, according to the Django URL configuration.
>
> If you’re hungry for acronyms, you might say that Django is a “MTV” framework – that is, “model”, “template”, and “view.” That breakdown makes much more sense.

Bear in mind that “Model View Controller” is just a pattern, i.e. an attempt to describe a common architecture. So a better question might be “How well does Django fit the Model View Controller pattern?”

Comment: This is perhaps the most direct answer.

Answer (score 11):

When you code, not thinking about names of framework pieces, there are no susbtantive differences betw, for example RoR. But it depends on the use you give `models`, since on Django they easily contain some logic that on other frameworks would stay at controller level.

The `view` on Django tends to be a set of queries for fetching data, and pass them to the template.

Comment: A `views` in Django is something like a `controller` in MVC and a `template` in Django is more likely a `views`

Answer (score 7):

In mvt, a request to a URL is dispatched to a View. This View calls into the Model, performs manipulations and prepares data for output. The data is passed to a Template that is rendered an emitted as a response. ideally in web frameworks, the controller is hidden from view.

This is where the difference is from MVC: in mvc, the user interacts with the gui, the controller handles the request and notifies the model and the view queries the model to display the result to the user.