# Should I use a 'view' to process a POST request in Django?

Tags: python, django, http

When the user submits a form for example, we want to send some data through an HTTP POST to a specific URL served by Django. I'm new to Django and I'm at the point where I have a handle to the submitted request within a view. From here I can parse the request and populate our 'models' however this seems to violate the MVC pattern that Django is trying to enforce.

Is handling the requests directly in a Django view standard practice or should I be delegating this somewhere else?

Comment: In Django, "view" is synonymous to "controller". It's standard practice to handle a form with a view in Django. Views can either be function-based or class-based depending on what fits best for your architecture.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you worked through the tutorials on the Django site? They'll give you examples of processing forms.

Comment: @mbradber Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621653/django-vs-model-view-controller Django follows MVC but not absolutely strictly.